# compare columns different dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I got two DataFrames I would like to merge, but I would prefer to check if the one column that exists in both dfs has the exact same values in each row.

for genereal merging I tried several solutions in the comment you see the shape

```
df = pd.concat([df_b, df_c], axis=1, join='inner')          # (245131, 40)
df = pd.concat([df_b, df_c], axis=1).reindex(df_b.index)    # (245131, 40)
df = pd.merge(df_b, df_c, on=['client_id'], how='inner')    # (420707, 39)
df = pd.concat([df_b, df_c], axis=1)                        # (245131, 40)
```

The original df_c is `(245131, 14)` and df_b is `(245131, 26)`
By that I assume that the column client_id has the exact values, since in three approaches I have a shape of 245131 rows.

1. I would like to compare the client_ids in a new_df, tried it with .loc, but it did not work out. Tried also `df.rename(columns={ df.columns[20]: "client_id_1" }, inplace=True)` but it renamed both columns

I tried

```
df_test = df_c.client_id
df_test.append(df_b.client_id, ignore_index=True)
```

but I only receive one index and one client_id column but the shape says 245131 rows.

2. If I can be sure that the values are exact the same, should I drop the client_id in one df and do the concat/merge after that? So that I got the correct shape of (245131, 39)

is there a mangle_dupe_cols command for merge or compare like for read_csv?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chris if you wish to check if 2 columns of 2 separate dataframes are exactly the same, you can try the following:

```
tuple(df1['col'].values) == tuple(df2['col'].values)
```

This should return a bool value

If you want to merge 2 dataframes ensure all the rows for your column of interest has unique values as duplicates will cause addition of rows

Else use concat if you want to join the dataframes along the axis

Comment: Thanks that helped perfect, for the merge I know can drop one of the columns, since both have the exact same values